# How can i take a screenshot from this page using selenium and java?

Tags: java, selenium

I have a page that is really complex to take a clean screenshot: http://www.carfax.com/VehicleHistory/p/Report.cfx?partner=ECL_0&vin=WBA4B1C5XFD418296

I tried this :

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver)
                    .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            try {
                FileUtils
                        .copyFile(scrFile, new File(Vin_Name + ".png"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

but didn't work at all, i also tried firefox addon to take this screenshot but it is not taking the entire page and i don't know why.
how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: looks like the page contains FLASH content and this is causing issues with WebDriver takescreenshot

Comment: Actually ther's no flash there :) but anyway thank you the problem was a css modifier that is making a problem, i solved it anyway thanks !!